# how to redirect the execution of a sql script (without the spool command) to an output file using a ksh script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, ksh

I want to run this command from a KSH script, which allows to run the sql script (without using spool)

```
sqlplus -s $CONNEXION_BDD @${FILE_SQL} >> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

but it does not work, she starts without any results.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a table called numbers and ran in some data:

```
create table numbers (num varchar(10));
insert into numbers values ('one');
insert into numbers values ('two');
insert into numbers values ('three');
insert into numbers values ('four');
commit;
```

And selected the data out using sqlplus:

```
$ cat get_num.sql
select * from numbers;
quit;
$ sqlplus -s $CONN_STR  @get_num.sql > get_num.out
$ cat get_num.out

NUM
----------
one
two
three
four
```

Here is another version that uses the here-doc:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s $CONN_STR  <<EOF > get_num.out
select * from numbers;
quit;
EOF
```

If you want to use PL/SQL:

```
#!/bin/ksh
sqlplus -s $CONN_STR <<EOF > tryCur.out
set serveroutput on size 30000;
DECLARE
   thisNum varchar2(10);
   CURSOR num_cur is
      SELECT num FROM numbers;
BEGIN
   OPEN num_cur;
   LOOP
   FETCH num_cur into thisNum;
      EXIT WHEN num_cur%notfound;
      dbms_output.put_line('ThisNum is:'|| thisNum);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE num_cur;
END;
/
EOF
```

This version produced the output file:

```
ThisNum is:one
ThisNum is:two
ThisNum is:three
ThisNum is:four

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: I want to run a plsql script that contains a SELECT query and redirect the result to an output file without using SPOOL

Comment: You said PL/SQL?  You did not forget the `set serveroutput on size 30000;`, did you?  If you don't include that, you won't see anything from `dbms_output.put_line`, `spool` or not.